# Why is XOAUTH2 failing for Microsoft 365 IMAP?

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0, office365, imap

I'm using the php-imap2 library to connect to Microsoft 365 IMAP (well, trying to). According to Microsoft documentation and the other questions on SO, it looks like this should be correct, but it's failing with a mysterious "AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2: A0001 NO AUTHENTICATE failed".

I've confirmed that security defaults are disabled:

[image]

And I'm requesting the following permissions:

[image]

I'm able to get a code, exchange it for an access and refresh token, and use the refresh token to get new access tokens. The latest response was:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "IMAP.AccessAsUser.All offline_access SMTP.Send",
    "expires_in": "5257",
    "ext_expires_in": "5257",
    "expires_on": "1669056062",
    "not_before": "1669050504",
    "resource": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
    "access_token": "*****",
    "refresh_token": "*****"
}
```

Decoded, the access token looks like:

```
{"typ":"JWT","alg":"RS256","x5t":"***","kid":"***"}{"aud":"00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000","iss":"https://sts.windows.net/82910404-f627-4ed4-9ec2-14854add3cf7/","iat":1669050504,"nbf":1669050504,"exp":1669056062,"acr":"1","aio":"***","amr":["pwd","mfa"],"appid":"***","appidacr":"1","family_name":"***","given_name":"***","ipaddr":"***","name":"***","oid":"***","puid":"***","rh":"***","scp":"IMAP.AccessAsUser.All offline_access SMTP.Send","sub":"***","tenant_region_scope":"NA","tid":"***","unique_name":"***","upn":"***","uti":"***","ver":"1.0"}
y��6[6�jÐ��K5)��D���p��ǚ��vQlY5bK8��q�Dp��V�onJ���[�
z�oc���P�1��O]�7C&@� �#[֐y�7l�6��ǋ�ݮ�ʝ����A�S!�m6&
                                                     �_
                                                         ��|t�C��J0�N��7ֆ��r��jg�+
                                                                                      Z�P!�
                                                                                            ��m��U��\p$�!x�Cݣ`�y��{l
iط|lq��S�#4�U#��5g6�w��n��&*��a"o��"
                                     ��W{(0H����"
```

The invalid characters look weird, but the scope seems to be correct. I'm using the following to connect:

```
imap2_open(
        '{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}',
        $username,
        $response['access_token'],
        OP_XOAUTH2
);
```

This gives me: "AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2: A0001 NO AUTHENTICATE failed". Can anybody see anything wrong?

```
DEBUG: [D3A8] Connecting to ssl://outlook.office365.com:993...
DEBUG: [D3A8] S: * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [TQBXADQAUABSADAAMwBDAEEAMAAyADkANAAuAG4AYQBtAHAAcgBkADAAMwAuAHAAcgBvAGQALgBvAHUAdABsAG8AbwBrAC4AYwBvAG0A]
DEBUG: [D3A8] C: A0001 AUTHENTICATE ****** [2354]
DEBUG: [D3A8] S: A0001 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

Comment: Can you get a protocol log? of the IMAP authentication process?

Comment: @Max, I've updated the question with the IMAP log. The authentication string is obscured, but I captured it as `A0001 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 dXNlcj13aWxsLnJlZ2V...`. Decoded, it looks like the expected format: `user=*****auth=Bearer *****`